# Polymorphic operator (updated (c++)

Tags: c++

I am trying to code a formula from propositional logic in a c++ class.
A formula can be:

1. A variable
2. A negation of a formula
3. Two formulas joined by a connective

I could not fined a way to define these three different structures into one class so I decided to declare them as different subclasses. The problem I am having is when declaring the opperators they do not seem to override the standard ones correctly. && is returning a bool instead of a shared_ptr

Solved: just used a shared_ptr in the baseclass to itself to avoid any slicing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

// {0, 1, 2}
// {and, or, implies}

class formula
{
    shared_ptr <formula> F;

public:
    formula ()
    {}

    formula (shared_ptr <formula> f)
    {
        F = f;
    }

    formula (formula* f)
    {
        F = shared_ptr <formula> (f);
    }
    
    virtual bool evaluate ()
    {
        return F -> evaluate ();
    }

    virtual string type ()
    {
        return F -> type ();
    }

    shared_ptr <formula> address ()
    {
        return F;
    }

    virtual void assign (bool b)
    {
        F -> assign (b);
    }

    formula operator&& (formula f);
    formula operator|| (formula f);
    formula operator>> (formula f);
    formula operator! ();
};

class variable : public formula
{
    bool value;

public:
    void assign (bool b)
    {
        value = b;
    }
    
    bool evaluate ()
    {
        return value;
    }

    string type ()
    {
        return "variable";
    }
};

class negation : public formula
{
    shared_ptr <formula> arg;

public: 
    negation (formula f)
    {
        arg = f.address ();
    }

    bool evaluate ()
    {
        return !(arg -> evaluate ());
    }

    string type ()
    {
        return "negation";
    }
};

class connected : public formula
{
    shared_ptr <formula> lhs, rhs;
    int C;

public:
    connected (formula f, formula g, int c)
    {
        lhs = f.address ();
        rhs = g.address ();
        C = c;
    }

    bool evaluate ()
    {
        if (C == 0)
            return lhs -> evaluate () && rhs -> evaluate ();

        else if (C == 1)
            return lhs -> evaluate () || rhs -> evaluate ();

        else
            return !(lhs -> evaluate ()) || rhs -> evaluate ();
    }

    string type ()
    {
        return "connected";
    }
};

formula formula::operator&& (formula g)
{
    shared_ptr <formula> temp (new connected (*this, g, 0));
    formula f (temp);
    return f;
}

formula formula::operator|| (formula g)
{
    shared_ptr <formula> temp (new connected (*this, g, 1));
    formula f (temp);
    return f;
}

formula formula::operator>> (formula g)
{
    shared_ptr <formula> temp (new connected (*this, g, 2));
    formula f (temp);
    return f;
}

formula formula::operator! ()
{
    shared_ptr <formula> temp (new negation (*this));
    formula f (temp);
    return f;
}

int main ()
{
    formula A (new variable), B (new variable);

    A.assign(true);
    B.assign(false);

    formula x = A&&B, y = A||B, z = A>>B, w = !B;

    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << x.evaluate () << endl;
    cout << y.evaluate () << endl;
    cout << z.evaluate () << endl;
    cout << w.evaluate () << endl << endl;

    B.assign(true);
    cout << boolalpha;
    cout << x.evaluate () << endl;
    cout << y.evaluate () << endl;
    cout << z.evaluate () << endl;
    cout << w.evaluate () << endl;
}
```

Comment: You need to define the functions outside of the class. Declare all the classes and then define the functions in the .cpp file (if this is a header)

Comment: The whole thing is flawed. I suggest you read up on runtime polymorphism and `virtual` functions in C++. You can't return a subclass of `formula` as a `formula`.

Comment: @user17732522 So I have been reading up on the concept of upcasting and I am still confused on how to go about it. So for intance I want to be able to say A && B where A and B are formulas and get it to call the constructor of connected and then upcast it to a formula, but when I call the evaluate function I want it to still remember it is of type connected. How do I create this class formula that encompasses the three distinct forms it can take on?

Comment: As an alternative to polymorphism via inheritance and `virtual`, you could also use `std::variant` and `std::visit`. But that seems like a different direction than you were going.

Comment: @OGrove That's what `virtual` functions are for. You want `evaluate` to be `virtual`. The operator parameters should be references, not by-value. The operators then also should return the subclass type, not a `formula`, since you will get slicing otherwise. The subclasses then need to store `std::unique_ptr`s to the `formula`s, also to avoid slicing. You might also need to implement some `virtual` cloning method for `formula` and the subclasses. I am not sure how familiar you are already with this stuff, but if you aren't I suggest you start with some more basic runtime polymorphism problems.

Comment: I am a mathematician but very new to coding. I updated everything to work on pointers. I used the normal ones and did not seem to have any issues with slicing (I did not understand the concept of unique_ptr). The trouble is my overloaded operator does not seem to work as inteanded, in returns a bool instead of a formula*. Code has been edited above.

Comment: Ok, so first thing, you need to change all the pointers to `std::unique_ptr`.  `&& is returning a bool instead of a formula*` Please post the code that reproduces it, please post the error message, if any. `very new to coding`  Well, consider python.

Comment: @KamilCuk Okey so I updated my pointers, I had to use shared_ptr because formulas can contain multiple instances of one variable. This is the error I am getting:  120:17: `error: base operand of '->' is not a pointer
  cerr << (A&&B) -> type () << endl;`

Answer (score 0):

You define `&&` to accept arguments of types `formula` and `shared_ptr<formula>`. This is weirdly asymmetric and will confuse you to no end. Then you are trying to apply it to two `shared_ptr<formula>`s. It is not going to work.

As a stopgap measure, change

```
cerr << (A&&B) -> type () << endl;
```

to

```
cerr << (*A && B) -> type () << endl;
```

However this is unsustainable in the long run.

I would recommend split `formula` in two classes, `formula` and `formula_impl`, where `formula_impl` contains all the virtual functions of the former `formula` and `formula` contains a `shared_ptr<formula_impl>`. `formula` implements what it can (`operator&&` and in the future maybe other things, like `operator!` and `operator||` and whatnot) and delegates `evaluate` etc. to the `formula_impl` pointed to by the shared pointers. The end user only sees `formula`, never `formula_impl`.

`formula` should also define *static* functions that return a variable, a negation, and a conjunction.

Some additional notes.

`assign` is not a very good choice for a virtual function. You can only assign a variable. It makes no sense for other types of formulas. I would get rid of this function entirely, and pass the value to the constructor of `variable` instead.

Base class implementations should not print "error", or do anything else. They should be *pure virtual functions* instead.

Magic numbers (0 is conjunction, 1 is disjunction) are not a good idea. Define a `enum`. Treat the `default` case as an error.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. I managed to get around implementing formula_impl by simply having a pointer to formula in formula. Also I need assign as a function becasue I want to be able to change what a variable is assigned to. What is the use of static function exactly?

Comment: "I want to be able to change what a variable is assigned to" This is probably better done in a different way, but don't rush it, do what works for you. "What is the use of static function" To create a `formula` that has a pointer to e.g. `variable` without ever having to see the `variable` class.